# Sseparate row and columns with delimiter and convert string into list and calculate sum of the last column from text file without using pandas

Tags: python

```
2019-01-01,Cake Fudge,150,1,150
2019-01-01,Cake Fudge,150,3,450
2019-01-01,Death by Chocolate,180,1,180
2019-01-01,Vanilla Double Scoop,80,3,240
2019-01-01,Butterscotch Single Scoop,60,5,300
2019-01-01,Vanilla Single Scoop,50,5,250
2019-01-01,Cake Fudge,150,5,750
2019-01-01,Hot Chocolate Fudge,120,3,360
2019-01-01,Butterscotch Single Scoop,60,5,300
2019-01-01,Chocolate Europa Double Scoop,100,1,100
2019-01-01,Hot Chocolate Fudge,120,2,240
2019-01-01,Caramel Crunch Single Scoop,70,4,280
2019-01-01,Hot Chocolate Fudge,120,2,240
2019-01-01,Hot Chocolate Fudge,120,4,480
2019-01-01,Hot Chocolate Fudge,120,2,240
2019-01-01,Cafe Caramel,160,5,800
2019-01-01,Vanilla Double Scoop,80,2,510
```

This is the data, I want to find the sum of the last column from text file

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('test.txt') as fp:
    data = [[int(col.strip()) if col.strip().isnumeric() else col.strip() for col in line.split(',')] for line in fp if line.strip()]
res = sum([row[-1] for row in data])
```

Month wise calculation of avg, min, max and sum for last column.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

with open('test.txt') as fp:
    data = [[int(col.strip()) if col.strip().isnumeric() else col.strip() for col in line.split(',')] for line in fp if line.strip()]

d, res = defaultdict(list), {}
for row in data:
    month = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%B')
    d[month].append(row[1:])
for key in d:
    values = [x[-1] for x in d[key]]
    res[key] = {'min': min(values), 'max': max(values), 'sum': sum(values), 'avg': sum(values) / len(values)}
print(res)

#{'February': {'avg': 350.0, 'max': 750, 'min': 100, 'sum': 1750}, 'January': {'avg': 261.6666666666667, 'max': 450, 'min': 150, 'sum': 1570},'March': {'avg': 425.0, 'max': 800, 'min': 240, 'sum': 2550}}
```

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: oh sorry i made a mistake,its working and thanks @komatiraju

Comment: how to calculate sum,min,avg of last column for each month

Comment: i have mentioned top rows only, data is for 3 months @komatiraju032

Comment: i have data from 2019-01-01 to 2019-03-31, same year

Comment: almost 13937 rows * 5 col

Comment: january  1421330
february 1422350
march    1739590

Comment: each month corresponding sales, i.e, sum of last column groupby month

Comment: add an expected output in your post don't post as comments